# HD Duplicate utility

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I easily copy or clone a boot partition onto a new hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/how-do-i-easily-copy-or-clone-a-boot-partition-onto-a-new-hard-drive)

I have two hard drives, one is empty and one is with data, and I want to clone one to other - 1:1 backup. What is the best tool for that?

Comment: With the limited info you've given, it sounds like _any_ disk imaging tool would work.

Comment: Take a look at [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I easily copy or clone a boot partition onto a new hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/32164/how-do-i-easily-copy-or-clone-a-boot-partition-onto-a-new-hard-drive), or [How to clone a Hard Drive to a slightly smaller Hard Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/88173/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-a-slightly-smaller-hard-drive), and [Clone a Hard Disk Content to Another Hard Disk](http://superuser.com/questions/207083/clone-a-hard-disk-content-to-another-hard-disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use linux (in general) ?

If so, simply use `dd` :

```
dd if=/dev/original_HD of=/dev/dest_HD
```