# Cloning and replacing laptop harddrive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure, clone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What utility can move my Windows boot partition over to another hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive)

My laptop's hard drive is dying and I have purchased a replacement. The current drive is 640gb and the new one is 500gb. I'm only using about 100gb of disk space so I decided to downgrade a bit. Both drives are currently installed in the laptop and the new one is formatted in ntfs. How can I go about cloning my old drive onto the new drive to keep my existing data and windows installation? Is this possible or do I need to install a fresh copy of windows on the new drive and copy my data over after?

Comment: You should just search your question, it has been asked many times. http://superuser.com/questions/88173/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-a-slightly-smaller-hard-drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`How can I go about cloning my old drive onto the new drive to keep my existing data and windows installation?`

There are a lot of dedicated programs for this task. To name a few: [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/), Norton Ghost, Acronos, ...

`Is this possible or do I need to install a fresh copy of windows on the new drive and copy my data over after?`

it is possible, and there are advantages and disadvantages to both. Briefly, a clone would have all your old programs, which is desired. But also all old cruft.

Personally I would make a clean installation. Run all windows updates and make a backup of that installation (for emergency use. E.g. in case you ever get a virus and need to restore). Then put the old drive in an external case and copy the data to the new drive.

This also prevents the extra stress of making a copy your old HDD when you already know that the drive is dying. (Since you only copy the files you need, not all of the OS).

Comment: I looked into CloneZilla but it seems there are some problems when cloning a larger HD to a smaller one.

Comment: I used Norton ghost in the past. While it did not allow a copy from a drive to a smaller drive it does allow a copy from a drive to a (small) file, and from file to a smaller drive. So it is possible. I lack actual experience with CloneZilla but I felt I should mention at least one free alternative.