# Is cloning a partially allocated 2 TB drive (src) to a 1TB drive (dst) possible?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, clone

I am thinking of trying to clone some clean installs of Windows OSes (dual-boot) from a (src) 2TB drive (1863 GB) to a (dst) 1TB drive (931.5 GB).

The 2 OS partitions on (src) would only be 200 GB total, and I could also have a data partition of 731.5 GB, for a total of 931.5 GB of allocated space (the rest of the (src) drive has not been partitioned).

So will Clonezilla, or if not what other cloning tool would, allow me to DISK clone the partially allocated 2TB (src) drive *to* the 1TB (dst) drive, *since they both have the same amount of allocated space*?

Comment: Read the link, sounds like it should work but no recipe was given on how exactly to do it.  I probably would need to make my (src) 2TB drive's _allocated/partitioned_ space slightly less then the (dst) 1TB drive, to guarantee a fit, and then expand it later.  If I do it I'll try to remember to post exactly what I did to make it work, with Clonezilla.  Thanks for the link @Twisty.

Comment: also [How to clone a Hard Drive to a slightly smaller Hard Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/88173/how-to-clone-a-hard-drive-to-a-slightly-smaller-hard-drive) is informative.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with Acronis True Image.  It is able to clone just about any source disk (including bootable disks) to target disks even of smaller size, as long as the partition being cloned is using less space than the target disk.

Comment: I used to use it a lot, and it worked wonders